# Is there a KTouch equivalent for windows

Tags: typing

Is there a KTouch equivalent for windows for learning touch typing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exits Many Typing tutors in Windows.

I will name some that I have used

> **1)** Typing Tutor
>
> **2)** Ten Thumbs
>
> **3)** Typing Instructor
>
> **4)** Mavis Beacon Teaches Typing
>
> **5)** UltraKey 5
>
> **6)** TypingMaster
>
> **7)** 21st Century Typing

For a list of freeware and shareware Typing tutors . Go here http://www.typingsoft.com/all_typing_tutors.htm

Comment: You must be a very good typist after using all those tutors.

Comment: Well no , I simply download them , test them for a few weeks to find whether they are good or not  and besides my brother uses them more than me

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with KTouch but lots and lots of typing tutors for Windows exist.

I have good experience with http://www.tenthumbstypingtutor.com/ which has a free trial version, but there are also free softwares around. [Just Google it!](http://www.google.at/search?q=windows+typing+tutor)

Answer (score 1):

Recently I discovered that KTouch works in windows as a part of the WinKDE installation, get it on http://windows.kde.org/ (I don't have experience with the rest of the port, I installed it specifically for KTouch).

Comment: The WinKDE installation doesn't work anymore. The project is closed and there are only custem build available for some programs but not KTouch.